# Python: Selenium & PhantomJS

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, phantomjs

I am trying to scrape the following website:
https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?keywords=coach%20&location=United%20States&locationId=us%3A0

The text I want to get is:

```
Showing 114,877 results
```

the HTML code:

```
<div class="jobs-search-results__count-sort pt3">
            <div class="jobs-search-results__count-string results-count-string Sans-15px-black-55% pb0 pl5 pr4">
                Showing 114,877 results
            </div>
```

My python code is:

```
index_url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?keywords=coach%20&location=United%20States&locationId=us%3A0'

    java = '!function(i,n){void 0!==i.addEventListener&&void 0!==i.hidden&&(n.liVisibilityChangeListener=function(){i.hidden&&(n.liHasWindowHidden=!0)},i.addEventListener("visibilitychange",n.liVisibilityChangeListener))}(document,window);'
    browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
    browser.get(index_url)
    browser.execute_script(java)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "html.parser")
    link = "jobs-search-results__count-string results-count-string Sans-15px-black-55% pb0 pl5 pr4" 
    div = soup.find('div', {"class":link})
    text = div.text
```

So far it looks like my code is not working. I think it was to do something with the execution of the java script.

I get the following error:

---

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-7cdc1c4e0894> in <module>()
      6 link = "jobs-search-results__count-string results-count-string Sans-15px-black-55% pb0 pl5 pr4"
      7 div = soup.find('div', {"class":link})
----> 8 text = div.text

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

soup output:

```
<html><head>\n<script type="text/javascript">\nwindow.onload = function() {\n  // Parse the tracking code from cookies.\n  var trk = "bf";\n  var trkInfo = "bf";\n  var cookies = document.cookie.split("; ");\n  for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; ++i) {\n    if ((cookies[i].indexOf("trkCode=") == 0) && (cookies[i].length > 8)) {\n      trk = cookies[i].substring(8);\n    }\n    else if ((cookies[i].indexOf("trkInfo=") == 0) && (cookies[i].length > 8)) {\n      trkInfo = cookies[i].substring(8);\n    }\n  }\n\n  if (window.location.protocol == "http:") {\n    // If "sl" cookie is set, redirect to https.\n    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; ++i) {\n      if ((cookies[i].indexOf("sl=") == 0) && (cookies[i].length > 3)) {\n        window.location.href = "https:" + window.location.href.substring(window.location.protocol.length);\n        return;\n      }\n    }\n  }\n\n  // Get the new domain. For international domains such as\n  // fr.linkedin.com, we convert it to www.linkedin.com\n  var domain = "www.linkedin.com";\n  if (domain != location.host) {\n    var subdomainIndex = location.host.indexOf(".linkedin");\n    if (subdomainIndex != -1) {\n      domain = "www" + location.host.substring(subdomainIndex);\n    }\n  }\n\n  window.location.href = "https://" + domain + "/authwall?trk=" + trk + "&trkInfo=" + trkInfo +\n      "&originalReferer=" + document.referrer.substr(0, 200) +\n      "&sessionRedirect=" + encodeURIComponent(window.location.href);\n}\n</script>\n</head><body></body></html>
```

Comment: Curious enough, when accessing using `Chrome` webdriver, the text in context is inside `div = soup.find('div', {"class":"result-context"})`. It could be falling into a logging in modal dialog when using `PhantomJS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the solution in `webdriver.Chrome`, because I have never used `PhantomJS`. There are two cases if you want to get the *results text*. One is that you are *logged in* on Linkedin from the driver instance and other is that you are not logged in.

Let's suppose you are not logged in. So the following code will get your work done

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?keywords=coach%20&location=United%20States&locationId=us%3A0'
driver.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
text = soup.find('div',{'class':'results-context'}).text
print(text)
```

Suppose you are logged in

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?keywords=coach%20&location=United%20States&locationId=us%3A0'
driver.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

class = 'jobs-search-results__count-string results-count-string Sans-15px-black-55% pb0 pl5 pr4'
text = soup.find('div',{'class':class}).text.split('\n')[1].lstrip()
print(text)
```